# Bootstrap daterangepicker add option manually using jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap DateRangePicker

```
$('#reservationtime').daterangepicker({
    timePicker: true,
    timePickerIncrement: 30,
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A'
});
```

I want to add manual option to this `daterangepicker` using Jquery. I need something like this

```
$( "#reservationtime" ).daterangepicker( "option", "minDate", '01/01/2012');
```

Is there any option available?

Comment: Check the DOC, there is an example... Or maybe we aren't talking about same plugin. Can you provide link to the plugin you are using? And what about a jsFiddle?

Comment: I have searched for the example, But I cannot able to fine how to add manual function using Jquery. This is the link http://www.daterangepicker.com/

Comment: So you want that: `$('#reservationtime').data('daterangepicker').setStartDate('01/01/2012');`?!  (i guess `setStartDate()` handles date format as set in option)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the setOptions method like

```
$('#reservationtime').data('daterangepicker').setOptions({
    minDate: new Date()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set/update minDate option like this:

Define variable

```
let myMinDate = '14/01/2023';
```

And then call it inside daterangepicker as option:

```
$(".datepicker").daterangepicker({
      minDate: myMinDate,
});
```

Or you can change some other daterangepicker options like this:

```
let someElement= $('#element');
    someElement.data('daterangepicker').drops = "down";
```

I think options needs to be pre set inside .daterangepicker({})